import/export data from one schema in one env to another env in postgres
due to challenges with data and its been current, there is a requirement to export data from higher env to lower env in automated way for certain tables.
Looking for any suggestions for bulk export/import (as manual process is very resource intense and time consuming)?

There are built-in replication features.

Your solution is most probably using replication.
But, as you mentioned -

for certain tables

You will not get that out of regular physical replication - as it is replicating EVERYTHING from one DB to the other.
Therefore - I will suggest looking into Logical replication, as it allows replication of certain tables of your choice.
Please let me know if it helps, and if you have further questions.
